# Get level member or value in mondrian

Tags: mondrian

I'm trying to get a Level member or value in Mondrian through Java code. Is there any way to do this?

I can take schema, hierarchy, dimension, and level through the getter Mondrian has, but unfortunately I can't find a way to access the value/member for each level.

For example in FoodMart schema,

Dimension: Store

Level: Store City

value/member: CA/WA/NY/ etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the .Members method on Level elements. The Database Journal has a very good [series of articles](http://www.databasejournal.com/article.php/1459531/William-E-Pearson-III.htm) on MDX where all these things are explained simply and geared towards new comers to MDX.

Using Java & Mondrian, this is done through the olap4j API. You can use:

```
org.olap4j.metadata.Level.getMembers()
```

For more details on olap4j, you can consult the [API online](http://olap4j.org/api/). If you need help getting started using olap4j, you should go through the [introductory guide](http://olap4j-demo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/Olap4j_Introduction_An_end_user_perspective.pdf).

Comment: Thanks! The web is a very great resource. However, I can't find the best strategy to deal with my task, especially in Mondrian.